# Смена цвета вкладки

Tags: c#, winforms

При выборе вкладки она обладает белым цветом (как на скрине).

[image: снимок экрана]

Как поменять на другой цвет?

Answer (score 3):

Если это у вас `TabControl`, то нужно задать у него `DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`, и в событии `DrawItem` отрисовать так как хочется, например:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SetClip(e.Bounds);
        string text = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text;
        SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, e.Font);

        bool bSelected = (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected;
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(bSelected ? SystemColors.Highlight : SystemColors.Control))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.Bounds);

        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(bSelected ? SystemColors.HighlightText : SystemColors.ControlText))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, b, e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2);

        if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == e.Index)
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();

        e.Graphics.ResetClip();
    }
}
```

Должно получиться как-то так:

[image: снимок]

Answer (score -2):

В TabControl открыть свойство tabPages и там для каждой вкладки установить background color

Comment: Ну это же не тот цвет...